# Import Nib View in Storyboard ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface

Swift 3 - Xcode 8 - iOS10

I have a xib file with a UIView. I want import this view in my ViewController.

My Player.xib

[image]

[image]

And my Storyboard result :
[image]

And my Class:

```
@IBDesignable
class EmbedPlayerViewV2: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var subTitleLbl: UILabel!

    var view: UIView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        loadViewFromNib()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        loadViewFromNib()
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "Player", bundle: bundle)
        self.view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView
        self.addSubview(self.view)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        subTitleLbl.text = "LOADED"
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I don't understand why my view does not have the good frame...

Comment: You haven't added any constraints from the EmbedPlayerViewV2 to the view controller's view.

Comment: I have said since I asked the question and it does not matter. My EmbedPlayerViewV2 is at good frame, but my EmbedPlayerViewV2.view is on top of my controller ...

Comment: The constraints shown in the first image are for the subviews of the EmbedPlayerViewV2 itself. Those constraints have nothing to do with how it's positioned within it's superview.

Comment: Yes but how I can set constraints for positioning EmbedPlayerViewV2 itself in it's superview ?

Comment: The same way you would set constraints on any view's superview. Click and drag from the empty white view to the superview, use the Pin menu, etc. In the future, it would be helpful to write out exactly what the issue is, simply seeing images with arrows doesn't tell the whole story. I would amend the question if you're still looking for a specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem.

```
func loadViewFromNib() {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "Player", bundle: bundle)
    self.view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView
    self.addSubview(view)
    view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

Tanks [Aaron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2981132/aaron)